# Safari CSS word-break: keep-all; is not working

Tags: css, safari, browser-support, word-break

I see that in the Safari browser the CSS `word-break` property which I need is not being used. Why ?

[image]

Comment: I use Safari v5.1.7 (7534.57.2)

Comment: Why would you need it? The answer to this question is crucial for addressing your real problem, now that the “Why ?” question has been answered. What kind of CJK (or other?) text have you got, and can it be manipulated with a script, and what types of breaks should be inhibited?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update** :
Safari now supports `keep-all` as a value. As of Safari 9.

---

`word-break` property is partially supported in *Safari*, i.e it only supports `word-break` if you use `break-all` as a value and not `keep-all`...

As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/word-break) (Read the note at very bottom) which says

> Note: Partial support refers to supporting the "break-all" value, but
>   not the "keep-all" value.

---

[Bug Report 43917](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43917) - CSS3 'word-break: keep-all' is not supported

Comment: if I use `break-all` it works in Safari, but it fails in e.g Firefox where it should be `keep-all`.

Comment: @Tony Well, property isn't supported so we cannot really do anything here, and by the way, firefox does support `break-all`

Comment: I mean, I want to keep all words it they're too long, not break 'em

Comment: @Tony so your are using CJK, try `white-space: nowrap;` but that will also affect non CJK text..

Comment: in that case it looks the same as here (select nowrap option) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_white-space&preval=pre-line the `normal` option changes nothing

Comment: @Tony `normal` will wrap the text where `nowrap` won't

Comment: Answer should be updated since it's 3 years old and things have changed

Answer (score 5):

I have found this to work:

```
selector{ -webkit-hyphens: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Safari 9 including iOS, `word-break: keep-all` is finally supported.

[Bug Report 123782](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=123782) - [CSS3] Add support for the word-break:keep-all CSS property