# CSS word-break:keep-all not supported?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to wrap all my text(Korean).

However, when I try [word-break:keep-all](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp), chrome and other browsers states that it is a invalid  property. break-all, break-word property works.

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: It's [fully supported in IE and Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#search=word-break), but only *partially* supported in Chrome. Yes, it's true, Internet Explorer supports things that Chrome doesn't.

Comment: @Praveen It is indeed invalid. Chrome display this orange warning icons on invalid properties.

Comment: Might Help: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141792

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#Browser_compatibility):

`keep-all` value is unimplemented in webkit (see [WebKit bug 43917](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43917)).

Similar topic on SO (Check [@MrAlien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542290/mr-alien)'s answer):

- [Safari CSS word-break: keep-all; is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703235/safari-css-word-break-keep-all-is-not-working/20703289#20703289)

Comment: I'd greatly appreciate if you could leave a comment after downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly Chrome does not support the word-break: keep-all property.

See: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43917